# Subplot background gradient color

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

How can I create some gradient color in matplotlib and then set the parameter `axisbg` of my subplot to this?

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111, axisbg='green')
```

Comment: woha, that's so Excel like! Backgrounds in graphs! This usually just disturbs the user from seeing the data itself. Please avoid it! (Although, technically speaking, the question is interesting, which is what saved you from a downvote...)

Comment: It's not my whish, it's just task. If customer wants background in graph and I can't bring him over, then...

Comment: sometimes customers ask stupid things, as a professional you should strongly advise them against that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't use the `axisbg` parameter, but may do what you want.

There's a matplotlib example for gradients: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/gradient_bar.html.
I tried it myself, this simplified version gives me a green-white gradient background (for some reason when doing this in the interactive python shell I need to call `draw()` in order for the image to show up):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt  
fig = mplt.figure()  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  
mplt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,1])  
plotlim = mplt.xlim() + mplt.ylim()  
ax.imshow([[0,0],[1,1]], cmap=mplt.cm.Greens, interpolation='bicubic', extent=plotlim)  
mplt.draw()
```

Pick another colormap for different gradients.
Works without `'bicubic'` interpolation too, but it's uglier then.

Comment: Each time I try to replicate this with my own data is is completely collapsing the y axis down to almost non-existent.  I have tried changing the plotlim values manually to correct this.  I wonder if it makes a difference in this situation that my data is a datetime index against two float sets of data.  Anyone else having this issue?  Further information appreciated.